# Find block hostnames in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am tuning MySQL and watch the [max_connect_error problem](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/011421.html).
I want to log hosts blocked by mysql before executing 'FLUSH HOSTS'.
Someone can help me, where to get the blocking information?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i didn't had such problem, but did you have a look in the mysql error file?

```
mysql> show variables like 'log_error';
+---------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                    |
+---------------+--------------------------+
| log_error     | /var/log/mysql/error.log |
+---------------+--------------------------+
```

I guess this is where it should be logged.

Regards